# Grid id is added to sort parameter in request, is this new?

Tags: jqgrid

I upgraded to jqgrid 4.1.1 and when I now sort a column the request parameter is:

```
?&sort=myGridId_title
```

Instead of the old:

```
?&sort=title
```

...where `myGridId` is the id for the grid container and `title` is the column name.

Is there a way to change this back? I need 4.1.1 because of a bugfix.

Comment: you should include more full code fragment. The best would be the example which can be used to reproduce the described problem.

Comment: I'm sorry but i am in a rush right now but I reproduced the behaviour by changing jqgrid version between 4.0.0 and 4.1.1 without changing any other code and the effect is that the request url (stripped the other parameters) changes as described above. I solved it by removing the prepended id in the serializeGridData-method

Comment: It seems that the problem is already fixed in the version of jqGrid from github. See [here](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/commit/57b758590f2fdb205345635fdef1c7de040fc5d7). You can made the same modification on the jquery.jqGrid.src.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out a solution to change it back.

I solved it by stripping the id, like this:

```
serializeGridData: function(postData) {
    postData.sort = postData.sort.replace("myGridId_", "");
    return postData;
}
```

Also, this was a bug that is supposed to be fixed in 4.1.2, just like Oleg says.